# Varying constant in Matrix calculation to generate 3D plot

Tags: matrix, graphics3d, linear-algebra

As suggested, I rewrite my code to make it simpler and directly showing the problem. Here is a short example. I'd like to generate 3D plot where x,y,z (= a,b,answer) while I am varying a (0

```
a = 0.2(*constants*);
b = 0.5(*constants*);
matrix = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 2}];
matrix1 = matrix[[All, 1]];
matrix2 = matrix[[All, 2]];
inter1 = a/b matrix1;
inter2 = 1/b matrix2;
inter = inter1 + inter2;
answer = Total[inter]
```

Comment: Where did you get the formulae you are using here?

Comment: Sungwoo, your question currently reads like a code dump. As @J.M. pointed out, you should show some background about what you are trying to calculate, reduce your code to a minimal working example, and indicate clearly why the output you currently obtain is not correct or acceptable.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I wrote it using discrete oridnate method. As you can see, I am still a beginner on Mathematica, but trying to learn and improved. Thank you.

Comment: Hi MacroB, Sure. I will try to reduce my code and edit again. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I was asking you for a reference, actually. Is there a book/paper from which you got the formulae you are using?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. There is a paper we just got accepted, but not available online yet. I might add the link later. But basics of this calculation is well explained in Modest's well known book, Radiative Heat Transfer. Chapter 10 and 17. We assumed that the light is collimated and no emission from medium.

Comment: So, is the $\tau^h$ computed by your code correct? Are you just asking for help on how to encapsulate your method into a function dependent on $\beta$ and $\omega$?

Comment: Yes, it is. Al least very close to the correct value. In my current code, beta and omega are constants to get transmittance. But when I tried to very the two constants, I can get the results correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to plot "answer" as a function of a and b is to build a function and then plot it.

```
matrix = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 2}];
matrix1 = matrix[[All, 1]];
matrix2 = matrix[[All, 2]];
ans[a_, b_] := Module[{},
   inter1 = a/b matrix1;
   inter2 = 1/b matrix2;
   inter = inter1 + inter2;
   Total[inter]];
Plot3D[ans[a, b], {a, 0, 3}, {b, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

For the particular function above, you can shorten this considerably to:

```
ans[a_, b_] := Total[a/b matrix1 + 1/b matrix2];
```

but I left it in a form more parallel to yours so that you can see more easily how to generalize to the case you have in mind.

Comment: Hi Bill, It works! I was able to apply this method on my long code to get 3D plot. Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.